# Model returns undefined property in post route but not get route

Tags: node.js, post, model, schema, express-session

In my static file:

```
    <form action="/confirm-purchase" method="post">
                <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" required name="name">
                <input type="text" id="address" class="form-control" required name="address">
        <input type="submit" value="Send Order" class="btn btn-success">
    </form>
```

When *Send Order* is clicked, the code should get data such as the `user` object and `cart` model and place them in the model `order` and save them to the database.

However when I click *Send Order* an error on the page appears saying it cannot read the property *'cart'* of undefined and that the error comes from the line where I declared the variable `cart` within the `post` route. The **same** variable was in the `get` route and that somehow caused no problems.

What did I do wrong?

In my routes:

```
// get
router.get("/confirm-purchase", (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.session.cart) {
    return res.render("shop/confirm-purchase", {products: null});
  }
  var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart);
  res.render("shop/confirm-purchase", {totalPrice: cart.totalPrice});
});

// post
router.post("/confirm-purchase", (res, req, next) => {
  var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart);
  if(!req.session.cart) {
    return res.redirect("/shopping-cart");
  }
  var order = new Order({
    user: req.user, //user is object placed by passport.js
    cart: cart,
    name: req.body.name,
    address: req.body.address
  });
  order.save(() => {
    req.flash("success", "Successfully bought product/s!");
    req.session.cart = null;
    res.redirect("/");
  });
});
```

My cart model:

```
module.exports = function Cart(oldCart) {
    this.items = oldCart.items || {};
    this.totalQty = oldCart.totalQty || 0;
    this.totalPrice = oldCart.totalPrice || 0;

    this.add = function(item, id) {
      var storedItem = this.items[id];
      if (!storedItem) {
          storedItem = this.items[id] = {item: item, qty: 0, price: 0};
      }
      storedItem.qty++;
      storedItem.price = storedItem.item.price * storedItem.qty;
      this.totalQty++;
      this.totalPrice += storedItem.item.price;
    }

    this.generateArray = function() {
        var arr = [];
        for (var id in this.items) {
            arr.push(this.items[id]);
        }
        return arr;
    }
  };
```

My order model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User"},
    cart: {type: Object, required: true},
    address: {type: String, required: true},
    name: {type: String, required: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("orderSchema", schema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked it out:
The `res` and `req` parameters in the `get` and `post` routes are in written in different orders.

My old code:

```
// get
router.get("/confirm-purchase", (req, res, next) => {/*...*/}

// post
router.post("/confirm-purchase", (res, req, next) => {/*...*/}
```

Should be:

```
// get
router.get("/confirm-purchase", (req, res, next) => {/*...*/}

// post
router.post("/confirm-purchase", (req, res, next) => {/*...*/}
```